# open alert window once modal submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

```
<div class="modal" id="myInquiry" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="myModalLabel">Thank you for your feedback:</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="inquiry">Feedback:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="inquiry"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="send">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I have for my modal footer.  I am wanting to click the send button and close the modal.  Once it has been closed I want to have an alert window or modal pop up and thank the user for giving their feedback.  I am new to web development and am getting stuck on this issue after numerous attempts (after finding different solutions on other questions) but nothing is working.

The modal's div id is 'myInquiry' if that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide more information, your whole code and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Okay, I added the entire modal div for review.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an action to your modal Close button, worst way would be like:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="alert('thank you');">Close</button>
```

you can add the ID to the button and then use jQuery to handle the action, and show something better than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add jQuery code like this.

```
$('button#send').click(function() {
   alert('Alert Content');
}
```

Then you can see the alert "Alert Content" when you click the Send Submit button.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal has a `hide.bs.modal` event, you can listen to that event and then, when the modal is closed (hidden from user) you can show the thank modal. Here is an example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x05z6wb5/4/). Cheers, sigfried.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem :), glad to help you, please if the answers served your purposes mark it as correct. Cheers and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding an

```
onclick="window.alert('<Your text here>')"
```

attribute to the button.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!